# Swift: test if a non-optional value is nil / not set

Tags: swift, option-type

I have the following line of code:

```
var info = [String : Any]()
```

Later i need to compare if `info` is not nil / set:

Something like this:

```
        if(info != nil){
            InfoCenter.default().info = info
        }
```

But XCode warns: `Comparing non-optional value of type '[String : Any]' to nil always returns true`

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do. Non-optional variable will never be `nil`. In your example it's an instance of empty dictionary.

Comment: Simple! You can fix it by making the variable optional `var info: [String : Any]?`.

Comment: You need to learn more about that because your example instance of empty dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the Dictionary is empty.

```
if !info.isEmpty {
    InfoCenter.default().info = info
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting `info` to be `nil`, you must declare it as an `optional Dictionary` like,

```
var info: [String:Any]?
```

Now, use `if-let` to get the value of `info` and check the elements in it using `isEmpty`, i.e.

```
if let info = info, !info.isEmpty {
    InfoCenter.default().info = info
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using following

```
var info = [String : Any]()
```

Means you have initialized info object, Which means its not nil it have a empty value.
So swift compiler trying to tell you that info object will never be nil according to above declaration. To remove this warning you can do use optional binding.

```
var info :[String : Any]?
**OR**
var info :[String : Any]!
```

Comment: Now op wants to assign new key to **info** like `info["myKey"] = "MyValue"` , then how he will do ?/

Comment: please chek question i have answerd what he just asked he can use guard let if let conditions to check nil and initilize it and assign the key value :)

Comment: He asked **how to check if a non-optional value is nil / not set**. but you changed the var from non-optional to optional. Its wrong.

Comment: you are missing this one 
But XCode warns: Comparing non-optional value of type '[String : Any]' to nil always returns true

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: just check @theTiger's  comment on question

Comment: But concept is optional binding is used to check the nil value and its value is not nil. Basically he does not needed that condition. Although he can check `info.isEmpty`  only. **Second** It does not mean to satisfy the warning we have to change the variable property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if info.count != 0
{
    InfoCenter.default().info = info            
}
```